# How to encode a large number of digital input signals into a signal result

Tags: digital-logic

I would like to know how I can detect simultaneous pulses on several wires.  Essentially I will have several wires that will serve as connection points when pressed upon.  A simple visualtization of this is if you were to view several wires draped over (but not touching) a metal plate.  The plate would be connected to the negative end of the battery & the wires would be connected to the positive end of the batter.  When touched, the wire will hit the plate & pulse.  Initially I was thinking something like a 64-6 encoder, but I now I feel that there are much better solutions.

So, in short, what is the best way 'hardware' to encode 2^n into n data lines.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to be able to identify which input lines, or how many of them, are "active" at any time? Also, would a simple parallel in serial out IC not do what you describe?

Comment: How simultaneous is "simultaneous", and what's wrong with the 2^n encoder?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily encode 6 digital lines into one *analogue* line. I remember my old Sony MD walkman used to do something like this to encode all of its buttons into a single line. Each button connects a different value resistor to the sensing line. The resistor values are chosen such that *every* combination of buttons creates a unique parallel resistance. This resistance is measured, and the combination of buttons can be worked out by the microcontroller.

[image: Resistors]

Here I have drawn the metal plate, and six wires hovering over it. Each wire is connected to a different value of resistor. What you are creating here is basically a manual [Digital To Analogue Converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter).

Some examples:

- No wires touching -> Output Voltage = Vcc
- First wire touches -> Output Voltage = Vcc x 1/2
- Second wire touches -> Output Voltage = Vcc x 2/3
- First and last wires touch -> Output Voltage = Vcc x 0.667/1.667

Comment: That's a cool improvement on my idea and a nice picture too.

Comment: Sony go better than that, their FCB camera blocks use a matrix of resistors to encode a LOT of buttons on a keypad.

Comment: I love this idea!  I'll make sure to give this a try..  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions pertaining to the type of microcontroller to use?

Comment: Can this circuit be modularized & then have several of the same circuit be used in parallel from same voltage source? (I am running into issues with the 2^n resistor values not scaling well with large numbers)

Comment: @Buck - Yes, you can have as many of these as you want, as long as each Output_Voltage line is handles separately (e.g. each one goes into a different ADC channel).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you are looking for something like a [wired OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection) setup:

[image: Wired OR]

In the above diagram A and B are isolated from each other (i.e. if B goes high, A doesn't), but if either goes high, C goes high. The number of diodes/connections above can be increased as much as you wish.
Or if you need things to be slightly more complex, then you could use a bunch of logic gates or even a CPLD.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to "detect simultaneous pulses on several wires" **and** you are not interested how many or which are contributing, then connect each wire through a 10k resistor to a common point and tie that common point to ground via 1k. when 1 wire touches the metal plate (connected to +5V) you will see 0.455 volts across the common 1k; when multiple wires touch the metal plate you'll see 0.833V (2 wires shorted) and this rises as more wires are shorted. Use a simple comparator circuit to detect voltages greater than about 0.6V and this should work.