# How to detect and identify multiple points of contact

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, resistance, converter

I am looking for a way to detect & distinguish multiple points of contact from force or pressure.  I have asked a related question at the URL listed below:

[How to encode a large number of digital input signals into a signal result](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61202/how-to-encode-a-large-number-of-digital-input-signals-into-a-signal-result)

The answer provided in this was to create a D2A & determine the contact points by extracting it from the voltage level outputted.  I have found this solution to be a bit 'clunky' as I will then be passing the original single into my roughly made D2A, which will then be passed back into an A2D for processing.

I am looking for an alternative solution to this problem.  Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Why does "clunky" cause you a problem? If you have (say) ten wires (I remember your original question) and you "combined" them using the D2A technique, you will get clunkiness and it is that clunkiness that allows you to distinguish between wire A and wire B shorting to the metal plate. More help needed understanding.

Comment: 'Clunky' doesn't scale well... I could require many wires so the potential variance in resistance causes an issue with the A2D input resistance on most Microcontrollers

Comment: are you saying the D2A system may not be the best way forward?

Comment: Well I really like this approach, I just cannot see how it will work if I were to use say 50 data lines.   As I understand it most A2D's on Microcontrollers have an input resistance limitation of ~2k-~10k and I would think that the variability of using this system would provide inconsistent results when read from a Microcontroller... Please prove me wrong so I can revisit this approach :)

Comment: To append to my comment - Since there are n lines & the value of resistances goes up by powers of 2^n, I can't seem to wrap my head around how to interface this with a microcontrollers A2D to provide consistent results... I would think there would be issues with the limitations of the Microcontroller A2D resistance constraints... Do you see anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the previous question thinking you didn't care which point was pressed and just wanted to know if any of them were.

Now I see you want to know which points are pressed, and how to detect a large number using only a few microcontroller pins. My suggestion this time is to use some [shift registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register).
These only require a few pins and many can be chained together to read a lot of lines and turn the parallel data into serial data to be clocked into the microcontroller. You need an SR that does PISO (Parallel In, Serial Out) and can be cascaded. A universal SR like the [CD74HCT299](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/cd74hct299e/logic-univ-shift-register-20dip/dp/1740109) should do okay. Have a look at Mouser, Farnell, Digikey, etc for more options - here are [lots from Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/shift-registers).

Now you mentioned "simultaneous", but gave no definition of exactly how quickly you regard this to be. I'm assuming that if it's to detect human touch, then it doesn't need to be that quick compared to a microcontroller clock speed.

For instance, if you are reading 256 lines and your clock is at 1MHz, then you are looking at around 0.25ms to clock all the data in - this is easily fast enough to ensure you don't miss a touch. Depending on the shift registers used (propagation delay, maximum number of serially chained registers - e.g. you could do two or four chains instead of one long one) you could go faster - many small micros have an SPI peripheral which can do up to at least 8MHz.

Depending on how you want to do things and how fast it needs to be, you could set it up as e.g a 8x8 or 16x16 matrix, scanning a row at a time.

Here is an example of two daisy chained SRs (from [this page](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftIn)):

[image: 2 chained SRs]

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention the response time again as well :) .... Well, I would like to detect up to 128 lines in a manner of 1 ms.... Is that possible with this solution?

Comment: My apologies... it is ~ 0.1 ms

Comment: I've never chained so many together, but yes, I think this should be doable with fast shift registers (if you check the datasheets specs for things like setup/hold, minimum clock pulse and propagation delay you can calculate roughly how fast you can go) You can always use two sets of 8 rather than one of 16 to speed things up (though you'd need 6 pins rather than 3)